# Is there any probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\mathbb{1}_{[x,x+h]}(\xi)\right)\neq 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $\xi$ be a real value random variable and $x\in  \mathbb{R}$, we define the function
$$\mathbb{1}_{[x,x+h]}(y):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \mbox{if }y\in[x,x+h]\\0 & \mbox{if }y\notin[x,x+h] \end{array}\right. .$$
In this context, the following question have come to my mind:

> Suppose that $\xi$ is a continuous variable with distribution $\mathbb{P}$ (which is usually unknown).
>
> **Is there any probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ such that  $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\mathbb{1}_{[x,x+h]}(\xi)\right)\neq 0 \:\:?$$**

**Remark:** Note that $\mathbb{Q}$ can not be $\mathbb{P}$ because  $\xi$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: What do you mean "$\mathbb{Q}$ can not be $\mathbb{P}$"?  What does $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ mean?  Are you changing the measure on your measurable space?  The question "Is $\xi$ a continuous random variable or not?" depends on the choice of measure.

Comment: If I have understood the question you are asking if the same measurable function $\xi$ can be a continuous random variable with respect to one probability measure and discrete with respect to another. Certainly this is possible. Take the identity map on $(0,1)$, let P be the uniform (i.e. Lebesgue measure) and Q to be the degenerate probability measure at $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @fourierwho The coment of KaviRamaMurthy interprets what I am asking.